# Why my tensorboard always give me inactive status after "loading active dashboards..."

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I used C++ to output some event files. I can see event files are created. When I tried to see tensorboard gui from my firefox. I got a gui saying "loading active dashboards". Yet, after about 1 minutes of loading, I got "inactive" stauts of dashboard and nothing showed up in my tensorboard gui.

what may be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? I remember Firefox being extremely slow with Tensorboard. Chrome-based browsers work much better.

Comment: I don't have a chrome with me. I can see event*tfevent* generated in my log directory

Comment: Take a look at suggestions here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/README.md#my-tensorboard-isnt-showing-any-data-whats-wrong

Comment: I tried an old version of firefox and now it works.